# lodash: insert property to another property within the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How can I map new key outside array key using lodash

here Is my array

```
 let data = [{
        item : {
            data1 : data1
            data2 :  data2
        },
        data3 : data3
    }]
```

I want outout :

```
let data = [{
        data1 : data1
        data2 :  data2
        data3 : data3
 }
]
```

Here Is what I try . I want to do something like this

```
 let data = _.map(data, function(item, data) {
            return { item.item, data3: item.data3 };
        });
```

Mysyntax wrong here.  How can I remove item key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need lodash for this simple work.

Just [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `item` and rest of the keys in the arguments of `map`'s callback, and then you can return the merged object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
let data = [{
  item: {
    data1: 'a',
    data2: 'b',
  },
  data3: 'c'
}];

const result = data.map(({item, ...rest}) => ({...item, ...rest}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let data = [{item: {data1: 'data1', data2: 'data2'}, data3: 'data3'}];

data = [Object.assign(data[0].item, { data3: data[0].data3 })];

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt map function will cut it what you need is to spread item with data3. Hope this works

```js
let data = [{
  item: {
    data1: 'data1',
    data2: 'data2'
  },
  data3: 'data3'
}]

data = [{...data[0].item , data3: data[0].data3}]

console.log(data)
```

Comment: that what I want thank you . can you explain more  a bit about ... nv use it before

Comment: be aware though, this answer will only work once. If you have a real array you must iterate through the array.

Comment: so I took the first element of the array, here in your array you just have only 1 element if you look closely in that first element you have 2 properties item and data3. All you needed was to spread internal properties of item with data3 so ... spreads an object and additionally i added data 3 as a second arg and you wanted wrapped in an array